# The strtok Function With char * Argument

Tags: c

I was just playing around with some code, and ended up typing something along the lines of the following piece of code. The issue seems to be that the `char *string` line isn't actually interchangeable with a `char string[]`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why `strtok(...)` throws a "segmentation violation" if my argument is initialized as a `char*` to a string, or why it would even require an initialization of `char[]` instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//extern char *strtok (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __delim);

char *string = "Hello world whats up?";
/*
  SEGV - Must be char string[] in order to execute.
  e.g. char string[] = "Hello world whats up?";
*/

char *delim = "\t ";
char *token;

int main (argc, argv)
        int argc;
        char **argv;
    {
        token = strtok(string, delim);
        while ( token != NULL ) {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't write your own prototype declarations of standard functions. Include the correct header file instead.

Comment: The problem is that `strtok` wants to modify the string argument, so you can't pass it a pointer to a string constant, which is read-only.

Comment: As an aside: It's a long time (maybe the first time?) since I've seen a question posted on SO using Old-Style (Kernighan & Ritchie) function definitions (as per your `main`). Worth an upvote, just for that!

Comment: [Why is a string literal immutable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294748)

Comment: I honestly only mostly-copied the prototype over cause I feel like it adds more completeness to the question at hand, am I wrong? On that note, I figured it was that it is wanting to modify __s, or arg 1, since it isn't const qualified, but couldn't it perform pointer arithmetic and still modify my non-const variable?

Comment: The `strtok` documentation tells to `#include <string.h>`, so that's how to import the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strtok` function (potentially) *modifies* the string passed to it as its first argument. That is the critical point, here.

In your code snippet (*not* using the `[]` version), your `string` variable is initialized to be the address of a *string literal*. That literal *is a constant* and is likely to be placed in read-only memory. Thus, when you call `strtok` and that function finds a delimiter character, it attempts to replace that character with a `nul`, which would require writing to memory to which it does not have the required access – and your program crashes.

However, in your version using the `[]` syntax, you are declaring a (modifiable) array of characters and initializing it with **a copy of** the string literal.

In summary:

```c
char* pc = "Hello, World!";  // pc points to a CONSTANT string literal
char ca[] = "Hello, World!"; // ca is a 'normal' array initialized with data
```

Comment: Read-only const memory without having to use a const keyword, thank you for the info!

Answer (score 3):

In C all literal strings are non-modifiable, they are in essence read-only.

When you define and initialize `string` you make it point to the first character of such a literal string.

This is the reason it's recommended to use `const char *` for literal strings.

If you want to modify the string in any way, and [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) modifies the string it tokenizes, then you must use an explicit modifiable array.